# How would you save user data in a list after the program closes without a text.file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

I need help saving user input to a list after the program closes without a .text file (If possible)

I have it as let's say Test_Password = [""] I defined the list but every time the program opens I have to set it to a blank string because if I don't it won't be defined.

```
     python
def Test1():
    ABC_List = [""] #--i'll have to set the list to a blank string
    def Test2() #--Another function to skip past the function that defines the list
        user_input = input("Already have a letter: [Y]/[N]: ").upper()
        if user_input == ("Y"):
           print (" ")
           x = input("What is your letter: ")
           if x in ABC_List:
              print (" ")
              print ("Awesome! \n")
              Test2()
           else:
                print ("You do not have a letter, go and add one! \n")
                Test2() #-- I have no way of saving the data
        elif user_input == ("N"):
             print (" ")
             x = input("Enter a letter! ")
             if x in ABC_List:
                print (" ")
                print ("Sorry, letter is already in list! \n")
                Test2()
             else:
                  x.append(ABC_List)
                  Test()
                  print ("")
                  Test2()
    Test2()
Test1()
```

Comment: You need to rethink your whole code structure. As it sits right now, it is not written in a style that is familiar to most Python coders, as you call your Test2 function from inside itself (recursion). This is generally not an accepted practice in Python as the language is not suited to infinite recursion.

Comment: Since it seems you are going back to Test2 no matter what branch of execution is being followed, you could rewrite your program to stay inside a `while True` loop. If you eventually need the ability to step out of the loop, just add a [`break` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=break#break)

Comment: sleblanc, that's the way my school taught it to me.

Comment: Schools do not always teach everything the right way. Try to find an example from an open source project and use it as a reference if your teachers claim that you should not do it this way. If they still object, then go back to their method, but keep in mind that in the industry, no one writes code like that without a very good excuse.

Comment: We don't have open source projects, we do our projects from a website called "PLTW" it's a school program. I can tell you what the lesson says word for word thought, just a small part.

- - - - - 
The if–else structures can be nested. The indentation tells the Python® interpreter what blocks of code should be skipped under what conditions. Paste the code below into your Python file. The line numbers will be different.

for example from the program it says:

if foods in food:
   if foods in citrus:
      return 'Citrus, Fruit'
else:
      return 'NOT citrus, Fruit'

Comment: I mean, I recommend that you use the `while True` method and that you find an example on github of a program that implements a control loop using `while True: … break …` to use as proof that it should be done this way if your teachers question you. The way you wrote it right now is absolutely not how it should be taught.

Comment: I'm confused as of why they would teach it the way they do if it would just cause problems, if they this isn't the way they should be teaching it then why does this method work at all?

Comment: As you wrote it, when a coder reads your code line by line, he sees a function inside a function, so he is already expecting you to return that inner function or do something special with it, but you are just calling it at the end. Why have it, then? And so, the coder sees user input and then conditions, so the coder thinks "ah! the program is reading once from the user and then doing something with it". But then, at the very end, `Test2` is called again, which is entirely unexpected to the person reading your code.

Comment: Oh, it works, but "working" is rarely the only criterion that your code should meet when you work for someone.

Comment: That again was an example, not the actual code I am trying to find a solution to. This code was just an example of the type of problem I was having because if I had called Test1() then it would have set the list to an empty string ignoring all of the data the user has entered, the school never taught me that I thought of that as a better way of storing the information because otherwise it would have just disappeared.

Comment: That is *not* the issue at hand. The problem with the code is that you are recursively calling your main function: not only is the recursive form not appreciated by Python developers in general, it is also not particularly suited to the Python interpreter as everytime you recurse, a stack frame is pushed. The interpreter has a recursion limit which used to be very small. Nowadays it is significantly larger, but it still makes debugging more cluttered as if your program has been running for 100s of inputs, you will have 100s of extra frames that are completely useless.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if I could just import a list from another function because if I define a function and try to call objects from another list in another function defined before that it will act as if that list does not exist.

Comment: I am just here to find an answer for how I might save user data by possibly a text file not to argue about how I code, if I could save the user data to a list like a text file and import it than I wouldn't have to do the recursion.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by importing a list. When you import something, it is exactly the same as if you defined it in the same spot that you imported it. (for all purposes intended)

Comment: Your code as it is not clean at all and it makes other users not want to help you, or even worse, downvote your question. It sits at 0 right now, even though I upvoted it. If you are not willing to at least make your code more readable, you will hardly get more help.

Comment: I just started coding last year, one guy gave me an answer but I didn't even know where or how to use it

Comment: To make things short: if you can't write to a file, you cannot save state. It's that simple. There are clever ways of working around that, but they are absolutely not expected from a first year student. Importing a module does not make you write to a file. When the interpreter runs a Python script, this script is only read in the memory, and the interpreter will *never* open this file for writing, therefore you cannot save state without explicitly calling `open(..., 'w')` on a file, iignoring solutions requiring network connections and a second machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some data to be remembered after your program finishes running, it needs to be saved *somewhere*. A text file of some sort would be one option, but there are many others - a database, various cloud storage things, many many options. These will all be more work than a text file, though.

Why is it you need the data save, and why do you object to a text file? It would be easier to offer a helpful suggestion if we knew the answer to those questions.

**Updated**:

Since this is a homework question, I'll give you some hints rather than doing all the work for you. :-)

As you've told us, you'll be handing in just the script, so there may or may not be a data file when your script starts. You can try reading the file, and deal with the fact that the file might not be there. In Python, we deal with that kind of issue by [catching exceptions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/error-handling/exception-handling-in-python).

Trying to load a list from a file, but falling back to an empty list if the file doesn't exist might look something like:

```py
try:
    with open('abc_list.txt') as abc_list_file:
        abc_list = [value.strip() for value in abc_list_file]
except IOError:
    abc_list = []
```

You can add to this list as you want to in your program. When you have a list you want to save, do something like:

```py
with open('abc_list.txt', 'w') as abc_list_file:
    abc_list_file.writelines(abc_list)
```

Comment: I'm in an AP class for my school and I need to develop a program, i'm developing a program for a health care app and they need the program. If I turn in the program they won't have the text file, unless there is a way to create a text file when the program runs if they don't have it already?

Comment: There is! I'll give you some hints as an answer.

Comment: @NinjaCoder, there are clever ways to hide data inside code. For example, you could open your Python script from inside your code and locate a position (typically at the end of the file) where you will literally write the list as a Python variable. I cannot recommend this approach for a school assignment or for a commercial product, but this is the kind of approach that some teachers might see as a clever way of getting around overly-restrictive constraints, as a "think outside of the box" challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save state without performing IO (input/output). If you cannot save to a local file, your only option is to IO to another machine (that is to say: send your data over the Internet).

Otherwise, to recover state from a file:

```
file = open('my_things.txt')

# strip() is needed because each line includes a newline character
# at the end
my_things = set(line.strip() for line in file)

file.close()
```

Verify if an item is in this set:

```
if "something" in my_things:
    print("I found it!")
else:
    print("No such thing!")
```

Add something in your set:

```
my_things.add('something')
```

Write items back to your file:

```
file = open('my_things.txt', 'w')

for item in my_things:
    file.write(item + '\n')

file.close()
```

Combining file operations:

```
with open('my_things') as file:
    my_things = set(line for line in file)

with open('my_things.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(item + '\n')
```